# Is there a way to get Round/Circle icon on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, icons

I'm working on an application on Android Studio and decided to try and change the app icon to a circle shape since it would look better. I connected this to my Huawei phone decided to see if it would work **but** unfortunately it instead outputted the default square icon. The strange thing, however, was when I ran the application on an emulator, the icon was circled shape.

Is there something extra I'm supposed to do when it comes to physical devices?

Comment: [Adapting icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) are the ones usually used now, depending on your sdk it changes, but you could specify a unique icon that applies to every device, what kind of icon are you setting on your android:icon="??"

Comment: My android icon = the image I want it to equal, so that works well and all, just the icon shape itself acting strangely for no reason. Yeah it must be my device itself

Comment: You mean a launcher icon on the home screen? Or a rounded `ImageView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate your icon through Android Studio's asset studio, but there is this [Launcher icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) that helps with that and you can choose a circular shape, then when you are finished, just copy and paste the generated files on your resources project directory and then use them on your `manifest.xml`.

If you use the second option, it will be the same on all devices, just keep in mind that on Android 10+ when your app is installed it will automatically draw a squared rounded shaped around your icon

[image]

**UPDATE 2022:**

Now includes android, ios, web, play store banner and more. https://icon.kitchen/

Comment: Tried it out and it actually worked well, thank you very much for the help man I really appreciate it

Comment: I've tried it and the icon is round. I want a square shape?

Comment: @HasIEluS on icon.kitchen at the end there is an option; "shape". You can use that to force your icon to be always square

Comment: @javdromero I did that but it's still round